# Multipart upload to S3 using @aws-sdk/lib-storage in React Native

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, react-native, amazon-s3, mobile

I have the following code;

```
 const readFileAsStream = async (
        fileUri,
        encoding = "base64",
        bufferSize = 4095
    ) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            RNFetchBlob.fs
                .readStream(fileUri, encoding, bufferSize)
                .then(ifstream => {
                    ifstream.open();
                    resolve(ifstream);
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    reject(err);
                });
        });
    };

    // usage example
    readFileAsStream(fileUri)
        .then(stream => {
            const upload = new Upload({
                client: s3,
                params: {
                    Bucket: S3_BUCKET_NAME,
                    Key: key,
                    Body: stream
                },
                partSize: 1024 * 1024 * 5 // minimum part size allowed by S3
            });
            upload.on("httpUploadProgress", progress => {
                console.log(progress);
            });
            upload.done();
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        });
```

The first part intends to read a local file as a stream and the second to upload it to S3 using the [@aws-sdk/lib-storage](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/modules/_aws_sdk_lib_storage.html)  package.

I tried converting the file into a buffer, blob or stream but I get various errors depending on the format such as "ReadableStream is not defined", "Buffer is not defined" etc.

This package is intended more for web so assumption here these are package error.  Anybody got any luck uploading a file to AWS S3 using this package in React Native?

Comment: Sadly I am facing exactly the same issue. I think the new AWS-SDK V3 is build with node.js modules which is not ideal for browsers. There may be some polyfill but I am still researching this.

Answer (score 0):

it's a *little* late but hopefully anyone else coming across this can have a nicer time.

I was trying RN to S3 recently to upload videos and also had some trouble, here is my solution which I have tested to work on Android and APK. Haven't gotten to iOS just yet.

```
import { S3Client, CreateMultipartUploadCommand, UploadPartCommand, Complet

eMultipartUploadCommand, AbortMultipartUploadCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-s3";
import { Buffer } from 'buffer';
import 'react-native-url-polyfill/auto';
import { ReadableStream } from 'web-streams-polyfill';
import 'react-native-get-random-values';
import RNFS from 'react-native-fs';
import moment from "moment";

declare global {
  var ReadableStream: ReadableStream
}
globalThis.ReadableStream = ReadableStream

const s3Client = new S3Client({
  region: REGION,
  credentials: {
    accessKeyId: supersecrets.accesskey,
    secretAccessKey: supersecrets.secretkey, // mustn't have special characters (dont ask why)
  }
});

export const main = async (path: string) => {
  const key = `${moment().utcOffset(0).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')}.mov`; // your filename
  const partSize = 5 * 1024 * 1024; // multipart needs parts of 5mb for all but the last part

  const fileData = await RNFS.readFile(path, 'ascii');
  const buffer = Buffer.from(fileData, 'ascii');
  const totalParts = Math.ceil(buffer.length / partSize)
  let uploadId;

  try {
    const multipartUpload = await s3Client.send(
      new CreateMultipartUploadCommand({
        Bucket: bucketName,
        Key: key,
      }),
    );
    uploadId = multipartUpload.UploadId;

    const uploadPromises = [];
    // Upload each part.
    for (let i = 0; i < totalParts; i++) {
      const start = i * partSize;
      const end = start + partSize;
      uploadPromises.push(
        s3Client
          .send(
            new UploadPartCommand({
              Bucket: bucketName,
              Key: key,
              UploadId: uploadId,
              Body: buffer.subarray(start, end),
              PartNumber: i + 1,
            }),
          )
          .then((d) => {
            return d;
          }),
      );
    }
    const uploadResults = await Promise.all(uploadPromises);

    return await s3Client.send(
      new CompleteMultipartUploadCommand({
        Bucket: bucketName,
        Key: key,
        UploadId: uploadId,
        MultipartUpload: {
          Parts: uploadResults.map(({ ETag }, i) => ({
            ETag,
            PartNumber: i + 1,
          })),
        },
      }),
    );
  } catch (err) {

    console.error(err);
    if (uploadId) {
      const abortCommand = new AbortMultipartUploadCommand({
        Bucket: bucketName,
        Key: key,
        UploadId: uploadId,
      });
      await s3Client.send(abortCommand);
    }
  }
};
```

A few notes on process. You will need [react-native-url-polyfill/auto](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-url-polyfill), [react-native-get-random-values](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-get-random-values), and [web-streams-polyfill](https://www.npmjs.com/package/web-streams-polyfill). As (i think) the sdk needs to be able to generate values (upload id and urls) on the fly but doesn't come with it by default.

Maybe just an issue in my development but your secret key also cannot have special characters `/ +` etc. Again not sure why this is an issue but it was...

I used ASCII encode since base64 corrupted so have a play around with which is best for you :D

[AWS Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/mpu-upload-object.html) where half of this was taken from